# How to customize data sources in the dropdown box of TFS work item templates

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-services, tfs-2018

How to customize data sources in the dropdown box of TFS work item templates?
The current situation is as follows：

[image]

The options in this dropdown box are fixed. How can I customize this data source, such as the value of the option coming from the interface query.

I thought about implementing it through plugin extensions, but I couldn't find any reference examples.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to read the custom data automatically from the XML process? Have you tried anything yet? As far as I know, when you using XML process, you need to export the process and do modification.

Comment: I have been using 'witadmin import/export' to import and export XML templates. But it cannot use dropdown boxes for custom data sources. What I mean is whether I can use custom plugin extensions to customize the data source of dropdown boxes in the work item window. For example, this is: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?view=azure -Devops

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported. However, you may add a global list ([Define global lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-global-lists?view=tfs-2017)), and add it to your work item type [Define pick lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-pick-lists?view=tfs-2017):

```
<ALLOWEDVALUES for="userGroupName" not="userGroupName" expanditems="true | false" filteritems="excludegroups">  
      <GLOBALLIST name="globalListName" />  

. . .   
</ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

Then you may use `witadmin` to export, modify, and import global lists: [Manage global lists for work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/manage-global-lists-for-work-item-types?view=tfs-2017)

Comment: yes,I have been using 'witadmin import/export' to import and export XML templates. But it cannot use dropdown boxes for custom data sources. What I mean is whether I can use custom plugin extensions to customize the data source of dropdown boxes in the work item window. For example, this is: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?view=azure -Devops